# How to decompile CompiledCode.bin extracted with Inno Setup Unpacker

Tags: inno-setup

How to decompile `CompiledCode.bin` extracted with  Inno Setup Unpacker.

The code is encrypted with something. and it only shows [null] and words like this please help me in decrypting this.

I extracted the code from a setup file that is given by my friend. But I could not get pass the encryption.

The file is attached with the given link :-

https://www.mediafire.com/?cnnhczfwt1dlrcp

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Inno Setup Decompiler site is gone.

<del>There is Inno Setup Decompiler project that is able to decompile the `CompiledCode.bin` file (extracted with [Inno Setup Unpacker](https://innounp.sourceforge.net/)).</del>

<del>As of now (version 1.5), it's far from perfect. But you should be able to read/understand the decompiled code.</del>